# Change global system property for file.encoding

Tags: macos, system-settings

Due to a conflict between the mac osx lion 'file.encoding' system-property and my java application, i have to change the setting from MacRoman to UTF-8. 
What is the best way to reset this system property globally for all users on this machine?

Regards
mmm...

Comment: What is reading this property as I do not think java does?

Comment: System.getProperties(); in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round, the issue is not the OSX default encoding which is UTF8, but Java's default encoding under OSX which is MacRoman

[Apples Mac Developer docs on Java](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/04-JavaUIToolkits/JavaUIToolkits.html) see the section 'Character Encoding'